# How to chain Future[\/[A,B]] in scala?

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

How I can do a `for` comprehension with the data of type `Future[\/[String,Int]]`

Here is a starting point, which doesn't compile.

```
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext,future,Future}
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def calculateStuff(i:Int):Future[\/[String,Int]] = future{\/-(i)}

for {
   v1Either <- calculateStuff(1)
   v1Int <- v1Either
   v2Either < calculateStuff(v1Int)
   v2Int <- v2Either
   v3Either <- calculateStuff(v2Int)
   v3Int <- v3Either
} yield {
   v1Int + v2Int + v3Int
}
```

Note: `calculateStuff` is just an example, there will be actually different functions, each depending on the result of the previous.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I should first note that I'm assuming that you have a good reason for implementing your own error handling (via `\/`) instead of using the functionality built into `Future`

If this is the case, then as your tag suggests, this kind of problem is exactly what monad transformers are for—just wrap your calculation in an `EitherT`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, contrib.std._
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, future, Future }
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def calculateStuff(i: Int): EitherT[Future, String, Int] =
  EitherT(future(\/-(i)))

val computation = for {
   v1Int <- calculateStuff(1)
   v2Int <- calculateStuff(v1Int + 1)
   v3Int <- calculateStuff(v2Int + 2)
} yield v1Int + v2Int + v3Int
```

Note that I'm using the `Monad` instance for `Future` from [Typelevel](http://typelevel.org/)'s [scalaz-contrib](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib) library.

Now `computation.run` will give you a `Future[String \/ Int]`.

If you need to inject a pure value into the computation, you can just use `point` and a type lambda:

```
v4Int <- 1.point[({ type L[x] = EitherT[Future, String, x] })#L]
```

You could also define your own type alias to make this look a little nicer.

If you want to use a `\/` value in the `for`-comprehension, you can just point it into `Future` and wrap the whole thing in `EitherT`:

```
v5Int <- EitherT(1.right[String].point[Future])
```

It's also possible to lift a plain old `Future` into the transformed monad with the (somewhat confusingly named) `liftM`:

```
v6Int <- future(1).liftM[({ type T[m[+_], a] = EitherT[m, String, a] })#T]
```

In this case you almost certainly want a type alias—that line's mostly noise.

Comment: Wow, that's what I was looking for, but could not get it to work. Your assumption is right, I do have a reason, at least for now. Thanks for this rocking answer!

Comment: How can I mix in a function that results plain \/?

Comment: thanks! I was afraid I needed add a lot of plumber or refactor the codebase to start using your solution. With your last examples, it can be used even only in the context of functions I am working on. Again, thanks!