# Is there a way to flatten nested monads of different types?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I am not sure how to describe this problem, so I'll just show the type signatures.

I have an instance of the following:

```
val x:Future[F[Future[F[B]]]] = ???
```

And I want an instance of:

```
val y:Future[F[B]] = ???
```

`F` is a Monad, so I have the following methods:

```
def pure[A](a:A):F[A] = ???
def flatMap[A, B](fa:F[A], f:A => F[B]):F[B] = ???
def map[A, B](fa:F[A], f:A => B):F[B] = flatMap(fa, (a:A) => pure(f(a)))
```

I think the following should work, but it does not feel right:

```
x.flatMap { fWithFuture =>
  val p = Promise[F[B]]
  flatMap(fWithFuture, (futureF: Future[F[B]]) => {
    p.completeWith(futureF)
    pure(())
  })
  p.future
}
```

Is there a concept I'm missing?

A bit of background information. I am trying to define a function like this:

```
def flatMap[A, B](fa:Future[F[A]], f: A => Future[F[B]]):Future[F[B]] = ???
```

Maybe this is conceptually a weird thing. Any tips on useful abstractions are welcome.

Comment: FWIW, I've solved this problem in code before using the brute force approach you have here.  I likewise didn't feel right doing it, but I haven't figured out anything better.

Comment: Welcome to the awkward and clumsy world of monad transformers!

Comment: @RexKerr are you saying this is the way to do it?

Comment: I'm more poking fun at the dirty side of monads: they don't nest gracefully.  Your solution is one way out.  Monad transformers are another, but they have various downsides (mostly the extra conceptual overhead plus the busywork required to create them).

Answer (score 7):

As Rex Kerr notes above, you can often use a monad transformer to deal with a situation where you find yourself with alternating layers like this. For example, if `F` here is `Option`, you could use [Scalaz 7.1](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)'s `OptionT` monad transformer to write your `flatMap`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type F[A] = Option[A]

def flatMap[A, B](fa: Future[F[A]], f: A => Future[F[B]]): Future[F[B]] =
  OptionT(fa).flatMap(f andThen OptionT.apply).run
```

`OptionT[Future, A]` here is a kind of wrapper for `Future[Option[A]]`. If your `F` is `List`, just replace `OptionT` with `ListT` and `run` with `underlying` (and so on).

The nice thing is that when you're working with `OptionT[Future, A]`, for example, you can generally avoid ending up with `Future[Option[Future[Option[A]]]]` in the first place—see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21993273/334519) for some more detailed discussion.

One drawback is that not all monads have transformers. For example, you can put `Future` at the bottom of the stack (as I've done above), but there's not really a useful way to define `FutureT`.

Comment: "but there's not really a useful way to define `FutureT`" Why is that? That is actually what I need.

Comment: It's [not possible to define without blocking](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib/issues/10). When you're working with `Future[Option[A]]` the corresponding monad transformer is `OptionT[Future, A]`, not `FutureT[Option, A]`—are you sure you need `FutureT`?

Comment: I am not sure if I need a `FutureT`. The only thing I know for sure is that I know I have a `Future` and some arbitrary monad that's inside it... I will go back to the code to see if I can structure it differently in a way that allows me to skip the `FutureT`.

Answer (score 2):

This may answer the "And I want an instance of:" part.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> Future(List(Future(1),Future(2),Future(3))) // Future[F[Future[B]]]
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[List[scala.concurrent.Future[Int]]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@41ab013

scala> res0.map(Future.sequence(_)) // transformed to Future[Future[F[B]]
res1: scala.concurrent.Future[scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@26a4842b

scala> res1.flatMap(identity) // reduced to Future[F[B]]
res2: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@4152d38d
```

Hopefully the below flatMap definition should give an idea of transforming the types :)
I replaced F with a List type for ease of understanding.

```
scala>   def flatMap[A, B](fa:Future[List[A]], f: A => Future[List[B]]):Future[List[B]] = {
     |     val x: Future[List[Future[List[B]]]] = fa.map(_.map(f))
     |     val y: Future[Future[List[List[B]]]] = x.map(Future.sequence(_))
     |     val z: Future[Future[List[B]]] = y.map(_.map(_.flatten))
     |     z.flatMap(identity)
     |   }
flatMap: [A, B](fa: scala.concurrent.Future[List[A]], f: A => scala.concurrent.Future[List[B]])scala.concurrent.Future[List[B]]
```

Comment: `sequence` requires a `TraversableOnce` (in your case a `List`), so it won't work for other types

Comment: In essence `sequence` does the same thing. It only uses `CanBuildFrom` to hide the mutation.