# Create a OptionT[Future, A] from a lower-kinded type

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

I'm pretty new to scalaz, and I'm trying to figure out to convert various types to monad transformers.

I'm stuck on trying to convert a `Int` to a `OptionT[Future, Int]`, or even to `EitherT[Future, String, Int]`.

I found a bunch of tutorials/SO answers that explain how to do this using `point`, but for some reason I can't compile them.

For instance, this snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21993273/857807):

```
1.point[({ type L[x] = EitherT[Future, String, x] })#L]
```

> Error:(9, 9) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type `scalaz.Applicative[[x]scalaz.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,String,x]]`

Another from [Scalaz Monad Transformers](http://www.47deg.com/blog/fp-for-the-average-joe-part-2-scalaz-monad-transformers)

```
type Result[A] = OptionT[Future, A]
"".point[Result]
```

> Error:(8, 10) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type `scalaz.Applicative[A$A35.this.Result]`

I believe this one should work as well, but it says method `liftM` is not a member of `Future[Int]`:

```
1.point[Future].liftM[OptionT]    //doesnt compile
1.point[List].liftM[OptionT]      //compiles
```

All these examples fail, but they compile if I replace `Future` with, say, `List`. Right now, this is the only way that works for me, but it's a bit verbose - I'd really like to be able to use `point` instead:

```
OptionT(Future.successful(1.some))
```

Why is this not compiling? Was the applicative/monad for `Future` removed from scalaz in a recent version?

I'm using scala 2.11.7 and scalaz 7.1.3. For what it's worth, these are my imports:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Importing an `ExecutionContext` will make your solutions compile, see [`scalaz.std.scalaFuture`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.std.scalaFuture$).

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

type Result[A] = OptionT[Future, A]
"".point[Result]
// Result[String] = OptionT(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@5e155fc)

1.point[Future].liftM[OptionT]
// scalaz.OptionT[scala.concurrent.Future,Int] = OptionT(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@60821af9)
```

Comment: Spot on! Turns out `futureMonoid` takes an implicit execution context... I wish those tutorials had mentioned this *detail*.